# Ошибка: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#, сокет

Пишу чат на c# используя windows forms, чтобы в серверу могло подключаться несколько клиентов. Не могу понять, из-за чего вылетает ошибка после подключения клиента: *System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."* в 58 строке.  Код сервера: `

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ServerProject
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 55444));
            serverSocket.Listen(5);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), null);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] buf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, buf, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
            Console.WriteLine("Text: " + text);

            foreach(Socket c in clientSockets)
            {
                c.BeginSend(buf, 0, buf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), null);
            }
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), null);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void sendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), null);` Последние два параметра метода: делегат, указывающий на метод и объект, используя который можно передать дополнительную информацию в этот метод.

Вы явным образом передаётся в качестве объекта `null`, а затем в методе к этому объекту `AsyncState` обращаетесь: `Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;`.